# Заполнить массив степенями чисел через foreach

Tags: java, массивы, foreach

уважаемые!

Вопрос такой.
Необходимо создать программу, которая будет заполнять массив числами возведенными в квадрат.

Код:

```
public class Square {
    public int[] calculate(int bound) {
        int[] rst = new int[bound];
        // заполнить массив через цикл элементами от 1 до bound возведенными в квадрат
        return rst;
    }
}
```

Не понимаю как заполнить через foreach, for работает.

код с циклом for:

```
public class Square {
    public int[] calculate(int bound) {
        int[] rst = new int[bound];
        for (int i = 0; i < rst.length; i++) {
            rst[i] = (int) Math.pow(i + 1, 2);
        }
        return rst;
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach используется,  когда нужно просто перебрать данные, например для вывода на экран, но не изменения данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
public int[] calculate(int bound) {
    return IntStream
                    .range(0, bound)
                    .map(number -> number * number)
                    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: нужно просто через foreach

Comment: foreach сразу не получится, тк там все элементы массива изначально равны нулю. Значит нужно перед ним, пройтись обычным циклом и заполнить от 0 до bound

Answer (score 1):

Через `stream` + `foreach`:

```
static int[] calculate(int bound) {
    int[] rst = new int[bound];
    for (int i : IntStream.range(0, rst.length).toArray()) {
        rst[i] = (int) Math.pow(i + 1, 2);
    }
    return rst;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = calculate(10);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    // [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
}
```

Comment: А ведь в первом `getRange` можно `int[]` возвращать, причем кода (символов) даже меньше выйдет. Возведение в квадрат тоже быстрее и короче через умножение, но это уже к автору вопрос

Comment: @Regent, ага, но мне было лень переписывать -- getRange скопировал из другого своего примера :)